# How to compare 2 arrays for same value and save them to 3rd array with true or false flags

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays:

```
var arr1 = [{name:"Option1"},{"name":"Option2"},{"name":"Option3"},{"name":"Option4"},{"name":"Option5"},{"name":"Option6"},{"name":"Option7"},{"name":"Option8"},{"name":"Option9"},{"name":"Option10"}]

var arr2 = [{"name": "Option 2"},{"name": "Option 4"},{"name": "Option 6"},{"name": "Option 8"},{"name": "Option 10"}]
```

What I wish to achive is that a 3rd array with all the values from arr1 with additional flag of **"marked":true** if that value is found in arr2 ELSE **"marked": false**

I tried a various combination of arry methods such as map(), filter(), forEach() but somehow not able to figure out how to return properly without repeating the values or making duplicate entries.

** What I see is that my inside and outside loop both statements are executed and I somehow miss the return true / false logic and end up repeating my loop the number of time equal to the length of arr2. **

```js
function test() {
  var arr1 = [{
      name: "Option1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option5"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option6"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option7"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option8"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option9"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option10"
    }
  ]
  var arr2 = [{
      "name": "Option2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option6"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option8"
    },
    {
      "name": "Option10"
    }
  ]
  arr1.forEach((el) => {
    arr2.forEach((el2) => {
      if (el.name.toString() === el2.name.toString()) {
        return console.log("Printing from inside the if loop", el)
      }
      console.log("Printing from outside the if loop", el)
    })
  })
}
test()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by mapping all the comparison values (name) from arr2 into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Then map `arr1` to create the new array and lookup each name in the arr2 Set

```js
const arr2Names = new Set(arr2.map(e => e.name));

const res = arr1.map(e => ({...e, marked: arr2Names.has(e.name)}));

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
var arr1=[{name:"Option1"},{name:"Option2"},{name:"Option3"},{name:"Option4"},{name:"Option5"},{name:"Option6"},{name:"Option7"},{name:"Option8"},{name:"Option9"},{name:"Option10"}],
arr2=[{name:"Option2"},{name:"Option4"},{name:"Option6"},{name:"Option8"},{name:"Option10"}];
</script>
```

Comment: that worked like a charm. just test it with the actuall data of 5k+ records and sorted it out just like that

Comment: `set.has()` returns a boolean (see docs in link). The new object is done with some *"destructuring"* from original object and adding a new property to it `marked`. `map()` creates a new array based on iterating another array

Comment: It's failry efficient since you only iterate each array once and Set lookups are O(1) complexity

Comment: yeah thanks for the ref link to was super helpful, one thing i noticed in my atcual code is that the result is a array full of promises any idea as to why i know its irrelavent to the question but arises in the answer 
**SnapShot**
{
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
     ....
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    '$locals': {},
    '$op': null,
    _doc: {
     ....
    },
    '$init': true,
    matched: true
  }

Comment: Depends on whatever api/sdk you are using to get the data with. Start a new question if you are having issues. This question wasn't set up for that

Comment: This is coming straight from MonogDb the actual useCase is that 2 models where 1st model has a field called **contains** which is array of objects that needs to return true if the value is found 2nd model.. which i saved in 2 arrays and then using the solution you gave created 3rd array.. and that one is full of promises.. also i check id any of the 2 prev arrays have the promises, they contain only data in objectified way