# How to get all properties of the second array of objects when comparing with the first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, npm, lodash, javascript-objects

I am using JavaScript with lodash and have two array of objects as follows:

```
objArr1 = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 300}, {'x': 1000, 'y': 2000, 'z': 3000}, {'x': 10000, 'y': 20000, 'z': 30000}]

objArr2 = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'a': 5}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'a': 6}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'a': 9}]
```

I am using the matching key as 'x' and I am able to get:

```
_.intersectionBy(objArr1, objArr2, 'x')

[{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 300}]
```

However, I also need to get the 'a' property in the second array of objects.

e.g.

```
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'a': 5}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30, 'a': 6}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 300, 'a': 9}]
```

Couldn't seem to figure out using lodash.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: "_when comparing to the first_" - in what way? What are the comparison rules? Is it "get all properties from both objects when the `x` property has the same value"?

Comment: Hi Randy, Thanks for taking a look.

Yes, you are correct. The match is based on the value of x however the matching pairs contain x, y and z property from objArr1 but not the key 'a' from objArr2 for the corresponding matching pairs.

Comment: I had Similar issue and it was anwered. Have a Look if that helps
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529536/how-to-compare-2-arrays-for-same-value-and-save-them-to-3rd-array-with-true-or-f

Comment: Thanks Nishant for sharing. Actually I'm able to get the matching pair. Now just trying to figure out how to get 'a' property from the second array of objs.

e.g. 

[{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'a': 5}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30, 'a': 6}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 300, 'a': 9}]

Answer (score 0):

This would be relatively simple to roll yourself without lowdash. The following `combineArrays` function takes a key and any number of arrays. It iterates over those arrays and puts any values into an object indexed by the desired key. Finally, `Object.values` grabs the final desired array.

```js
const objArr1 = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 300}, {'x': 1000, 'y': 2000, 'z': 3000}, {'x': 10000, 'y': 20000, 'z': 30000}];

const objArr2 = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'a': 5}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'a': 6}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'a': 9}];

function combineArrays(key, ...arrs) {
  const result = {};
  const counts = {};
  arrs.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(el => {
      result[el[key]] = { ...result[el[key]], ...el }; 
      counts[el[key]] = (counts[el[key]] || 0) + 1;
    });
  });
  return Object.values(result).filter(obj => 
    counts[obj[key]] > 1
  );
}

console.log(
  combineArrays("x", objArr1, objArr2)
);
```

Importantly, if there are any conflicts between any of the arrays, the array listed later in the function call will win.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This seems to work. However returns non matching pairs as well.

[ { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, a: 5 }, { x: 10, y: 20, z: 30, a: 6 }, { x: 100, y: 200, z: 300, a: 9 }, { x: 1000, y: 2000, z: 3000 }, { x: 10000, y: 20000, z: 30000 } ]

Looking to get only the matching pairs.

e.g.

[ { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, a: 5 }, { x: 10, y: 20, z: 30, a: 6 }, { x: 100, y: 200, z: 300, a: 9 }]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, the function now implements a `count` and will `filter` out any object keys that don't come up more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.keyBy()` to create a dictionary of objects by their `x` value out of `objArr2` (`objArr2Dict`). Iterate the results of the intersection, and merge each item with the respective item from the dictionary.

```js
const objArr1 = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 300}, {'x': 1000, 'y': 2000, 'z': 3000}, {'x': 10000, 'y': 20000, 'z': 30000}]

const objArr2 = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'a': 5}, {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'a': 6}, {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'a': 9}]

const objArr2Dict = _.keyBy(objArr2, 'x')

const result = _.map(
  _.intersectionBy(objArr1, objArr2, 'x'),
  o => ({ ...o, ...objArr2Dict[o.x] })
)
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```